# Alternative data formatting

Tags: c

I have two struct objects storing two different dates. I wish to ensure that they have the format of either (dd/mm/yyyy) | (dd-mm-yyyy) and then to take the difference them.

Print stderror if it's not in the format of dd/mm/yyyy however it doesn't seem to accept both formats.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

/*
# Objective: date1.c is to write in two dates and determine the difference 
in the number of days between them.
Must be date inputs must be written into console as <day>/<month>/<year> | 
<day>-<month>-<year>
*/ 

int minimumYear = 0; // O AD
int maximumYear = 10000; // 10000 AD

// Struct for the date
typedef struct {
    int dd;
    int mm;
    int yyyy;
} dateFormat;
```

Main source of confusion...

```
int main() {
    dateFormat getDate1;
    dateFormat getDate2;

    //input correct date
    fprintf(stderr, "Enter date in format (day/month/year): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &getDate1.dd, &getDate1.mm, &getDate1.yyyy);

    fprintf(stderr, "Enter date in format (day/month/year): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &getDate2.dd, &getDate2.mm, &getDate2.yyyy);


}
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks I attempted to make it adhere more to the standards.

Comment: I think you should read the link again. Then try to compile the code you show here, it will fail. Then try to compile the code conveniently, i.e. without copying twice or editing. Can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the input as a string into an array with `fgets()` and try and parse it with `sscanf()` according to both formats. Complain if neither format matches the input:

```
int main() {
    char buf[128];
    dateFormat getDate1;

    //input correct date
    fprintf(stderr, "Enter date in format (day/month/year): ");
    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "premature end of file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (sscanf(buf, "%d/%d/%d", &getDate1.dd, &getDate1.mm, &getDate1.yyyy) != 3
    &&  sscanf(buf, "%d-%d-%d", &getDate1.dd, &getDate1.mm, &getDate1.yyyy) != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid date: %s", buf);
        return 1;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Osman: One of the primary benefits of 'read a line and then parse it with `sscanf()`' is precisely that you can try to parse the data using different formats, which is extremely difficult to do 100% reliably when calling `scanf()` or `fscanf()` directly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, will bear that in mind :)